# How can create a separate click event for each input button displayed using a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, mysqli

I am listing users from the database in a table. for each user; there is an 'Approve' and 'Reject' button.
I want to put my code in such way that when i click each button for each user,only the approval or the reject event should affect that specific user? My table looks like this:

[image]
right now when i click 'approve' on one user, the other user's approval event also gets triggered. here is my approval code:

```
$sql = "select * from user_table ORDER BY date_registered DESC LIMIT 10";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
 {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $emailadr = $row["email"];
    $adresses [] = $emailadr;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["firstname"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["lastname"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["idnumber"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["qualification"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["dofa"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["date_registered"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<button  name="approve" value='. $row["user_id"].'>Approve</button> <button  name="reject" value='. $row["user_id"].'>Reject</button>';
    echo "</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
     }
            if(isset($_POST['approve'])){
           // Approved user ID is now in $_POST['approve']
           mail($adresses[$row["user_id"]],'subect 
           1','approved','From:email@example.com');
       }elseif(isset($_POST['reject'])){
    // 
    }

  }

print_r($adresses);
```

Comment: is event in jquery,javascript? plz add html code & explain more about php code

Comment: I have added an updated code above. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When inserting new users, you normally have a auto increment column that relates to each row or user (generally called ID) you can do it a few ways first thing you need to do is include that ID or value so you know which user to change:

Create your Buttons:

```
<button name="approve" value="5"> Approve</button>
<button name="reject" value="5"> Reject</button>
```

You would update the value to your user ID

You can then simply check whether you have Approved or Rejected the user:

```
if(isset($_POST['approve'])){
    // Approved user ID is now in $_POST['approve']
}elseif(isset($_POST['reject'])){
    // Rejected user ID is now in $_POST['reject']
}
```

To get `$adresses` you need to assign it outside the loop. Also updated `$adresses []` to `array_push($adresses, $row["email"]);` just because of preference but can be changed back if you prefer.

```
<?php

$adresses = array();
$sql = "select * from user_table ORDER BY date_registered DESC LIMIT 10";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($adresses, $row["email"]);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["firstname"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["lastname"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["idnumber"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["qualification"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["dofa"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["date_registered"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<button name="approve" value='. $row["user_id"].'>Approve</button> <button name="reject" value='. $row["user_id"].'>Reject</button>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['approve'])){
        mail($adresses[$_POST["approve"]],'subect 1','approved','From:email@example.com'); 
        //update DB to approved
    }elseif(isset($_POST['reject'])){
        //update DB to rejected
    }

}

print_r($adresses);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. i did parse the id in the buttons, but i'm still getting the same results. i don't if maybe it's because i'm calling the submit event while im still inside the while loop? should I call the submit event outside of the loop? and if so, how am i going store the users id's so that i don't get the 'undefined index' error on the code?

Comment: You need to define `$adresses` outside the while if you want to use it. `$adresses[$row["user_id"]]` is not what you want either, $row will probably give you the last row, we are sending the user id in `$_POST['approve']` would become `$adresses[$_POST["approve"]]`

Comment: i'm sorry for sounding very dumb right now.  I am struggling to define the $addresses outside of the while loop. it picks the last address, as you have indicated. but i dont how i can store these values inside the variable. i have this:   if(isset($_POST['approve'])){
           // Approved user ID is now in $_POST['approve']
           mail($adresses[$_POST['approve']],'subect 
           1','ereew','From:email@example.com');
 } just below the print_r()function, but it's still picking up the last address

Comment: Thank you very much. the code still l execute for the last index.i did a print_r($_POST) and this is what i get: Array ( [approve] => 2 ). doesn't this also mean i must store $_POST in an array?

Comment: `$_POST` is only sent when you click the button. `var_dump($adresses);` just after mail and post results, it should be collecting all the emails

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. Passing the contentid or some unique identifier will solve this.